# when the code throw many exception and the handle is same, which choice is better?

Tags: java, exception

when the code throw many exception and the handle is same, which choice is better?

```
try{
}catch(ExceptionOne e1)
{
someHandle()
}
catch(ExceptionTwo e2){
someHandle()
}
catch(ExceptionThree e3)
{
someHandle()
}
```

or

```
try{
}catch(Exception e1)
{
someHandle()
}
```

some books meationed that when encoutering exception, try catch it clearly , not try cacth all exception.

So which is better?

Comment: Use general catches only for logging. See: http://codeisland.org/2012/catching-practice/

Comment: If all the exceptions are related, say they are part of a inheritance sub-hierarchy, you could catch the common ancestor so long as it isn't too general for your context (e.g. catching IOExceptions instead of EOFException, FileNotFoundException, etc., etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is better. The second catches all exceptions, and that might include some exceptions that you do not want to catch.

If you upgrade to Java 7 you could use a [catch block that can catch more than one type of exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), which is a cleaner solution.

```
try {
    // Something that might throw.
}
catch(ExceptionOne | ExceptionTwo | ExceptionThree e) {
    someHandle()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about what the exception is, you can just throw the general "Exception:"

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {

  }
```

Comment: If you don't care? You really should care, and this sort of capture of all exceptions should be discouraged not encouraged. 1+ to @MarkByers who has the much better answer to the original question.

Comment: -1 - In SO we aspire to teaching people good coding practice, not get-the-code-out-the-door-quick hackery.  (Besides your answer talks about "throwing" Exception and then provides an irrelevant example of catching it ... which just repeats the example in the question.)